# cout.width and cout.fill return different output

Tags: c++

```
int main(){  
float f = 10.12345;  
cout.width(10);  
cout.fill('*');  
cout<< f << endl;  
cout<< f << endl;   
}
```

first cout statement output
I expected output is **10.12345 but it was ***10.1235
Second cout statement output
I expected output is 10.12345 but it was 10.1235
Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: The default precision is 6, that's why you only see 6 decimal digits being printed. See [`std::ios_base::precision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value of float is being rounded to 4 decimal places because of the default precision value (6), refer to `ios_base::precision` hence `10.12345` ends up being `10.1235`

further more, the 1st output has a width of 10, and the value `10.1235` has 7 characters in it, leaving 3 to filled with `*` hence the output `***10.1235`

finally the last answer is the rounded one due to default precision: `10.1235`